# I want a single page scroll with top nav menu scroll and active (Active menu should be in first position scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, single-page-application, jquery-ui-tabs

I am not able to scroll Nav menu with left or right position.
This should be work automatically when page is scrolling.

**For Examples :**

1. if "Menu 2" active then scroll position on first for Menu 2
2. if "Menu 3" active then scroll position on first for Manu 3

That above scroll and position should be automatically active on page scroll.

It is working for me when i am clicking on to the each menu. Because page scroll with top position is working fine. On click it is working but on scroll it is not working for me.

[image]

```
I am using that reference :https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/
```

Comment: I am trying this. 
var scrollTo = $('#'+target).position().left; 
$scroller.animate({'scrollLeft': scrollTo}, 500);

Comment: Anyone can fix it?